# I am trying to figure out why my code is not working

Tags: java, arrays

For some reason, I am not able to print my array as a string
I cannot find any error in the syntax either.
[image]

Comment: Please post code as text not as images

Answer (score 1):

The name of your class is conflicting with the library.

Comment: Good. Glad it worked. Friendly reminder though, PraveenSP is right. You shouldn't post code as images for several reasons: 1) If someone wants to reproduce your code to help debug they can't. No one will manually retype it. 2) Its inefficient. Sending an image is much heavier than text. 3) screenshots are way more likely to accidentally reveal personal information.

Comment: Omg sorry
This is my first time using stack overflow

Comment: I was not aware of this. I will post the code properly next time

Comment: No problem at all. Learning all of the norms takes time. Welcome to SO

Answer (score 1):

You called your class `Arrays`. So the `Arrays` in `Arrays.toString(...)` refers to **your** `Arrays` class, not `java.util.Arrays` And **your** `Arrays` class doesn't have a `toString(int[])` method, so your code isn't compiling correctly.

Fix it by either renaming your class to something other than `Arrays` (so that `Arrays` can now unambiguously mean the `java.util.Arrays` class you imported), or by writing `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays(a));` (to clarify exactly which `Arrays` class you meant).